# Get label from checked input

Tags: jquery

I'd like to get the label `.text()` from checked inputs. Actually, my code check if an input is checked and then get the label from every `<li>` with same class and not only the checked ones. How can I achieved that? I think that I should use the .parent() or .child() attribute but I don't know how.

I've tried with `alert($('#myId input').parent('label').text());` but without success.

**Codepen**
https://codepen.io/Qasph/pen/LyNJev?editors=1010

```js
$('#result').click(function() {
  // If an input is checked
  if ($('#myId input').is(':checked')) {
    // Get text from label parent
    console.log($('#myId label').text());
  } else {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myId">
  <ul>
    <!-- First class -->
    <li class="myFirstClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">1 - First class</label></li>
    <li class="myFirstClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="6">2 - First class</label></li>
    <!-- Second class -->
    <li class="mySecondClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">1bis - Second class</label></li>
    <li class="mySecondClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="6">2bis - Second class</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="result">Result</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `map()` to loop over all `:checked` checkboxes and build an array of the text values of the parent `label` element. Try this:

```js
$('#result').click(function() {
  var labels = $('#myId :checked').map(function() {
    return $(this).closest('label').text();
  }).get();
  
  console.log(labels);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myId">
  <ul>
    <li class="myFirstClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">1 - First class</label></li>
    <li class="myFirstClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="6">2 - First class</label></li>
    <li class="mySecondClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">1bis - Second class</label></li>
    <li class="mySecondClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="6">2bis - Second class</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="result">Result</button>
```

Comment: Yep, it always gets me :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#result').click(function() {
  // If an input is checked
  $('#myId input').each(function() {
      if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        console.log($(this).parent().text());
      }
  })
});
```

Alternative to Rory's answer. Simply checks each input if it's checked (a bit easier to read and understand, but does the exact same thing).

Comment: You could use `$('#myId input:checked')` and avoid the `if` :)

Comment: Yep and it would save *some* computation power ;)

Answer (score 2):

Loop or map the checked inputs and grab the parent or closest label

```js
$('#result').click(function() {
  // If an input is checked
  var result = [];
  $('#myId input:checked').each(function() { // or map
    result.push($(this).parent().text())
  });
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myId">
  <ul>
    <!-- First class -->
    <li class="myFirstClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">1 - First class</label></li>
    <li class="myFirstClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="6">2 - First class</label></li>
    <!-- Second class -->
    <li class="mySecondClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">1bis - Second class</label></li>
    <li class="mySecondClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="6">2bis - Second class</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="result">Result</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the text for checked checkboxes labels, i would just ask for them ;)

```js
$('#result').click(function() {
  var $checkedInputs = $('input:checked');
  
  if ($checkedInputs.length !== -1) {
    $checkedInputs.each(function (i) {
      alert($checkedInputs.eq(i).parent().text());
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myId">
  <ul>
    <!-- First class -->
    <li class="myFirstClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">1 - First class</label></li>
    <li class="myFirstClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="6">2 - First class</label></li>
    <!-- Second class -->
    <li class="mySecondClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="3">1bis - Second class</label></li>
    <li class="mySecondClass"><label><input type="checkbox" value="6">2bis - Second class</label></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="result">Result</button>
```

Comment: `$checkedInputs.each(function (i) {
      alert($checkedInputs.eq(i).parent().text());
    });` and `$checkedInputs.each(function () {
      alert($(this).parent().text());
    });` work the same. Why needlessly index?